# Unable to figure out the object in same identifier value in Spring-boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest

"trace": "org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session : [com.ffcalendar.calendarDemo.models.User#1]; nested exception is javax.persistence.EntityExistsException: A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session : [com.ffcalendar.calendarDemo.models.User#1]\r\n\tat org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:400)\r\n\tat org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:235)\r\n\tat org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:551)\r\n\tat org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61)\r\n\tat org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:242)\r\n\tat org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:152)\r\n\tat

Comment: Do your entities have a proper `equals` and `hashCode` implementation?

Comment: yes, not for all fields but the ones necessary.

Comment: @ShreyashSharma share with us the code that make those saves

Answer (score 0):

> "A different object with the same identifier value was already
> associated with the session"

Only 1 managed instance with a specific id is allowed in persistence context. This means that for a specific class you can have only 1 instance with for example `id =322` which is considered to be in managed state from JPA. If you have another detached instance from the same class with the same Id and you try to re-attach it then you receive the error that you have.

If you give more information about how you save those entities, we will be able to find where the wrong is.

The root cause though is what I described.

**Edit**: After providing more info in the question

I have many suspicions as your code does not seem very clean but I will start with the obvious anyways

```
public class CalendarEvent {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

     @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            final int prime = 31;
            int result = 1;
            result = prime * result + ((eventDateTime == null) ? 0 : eventDateTime.hashCode());
            return result;
        }
    
        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            if (this == obj)
                return true;
            if (obj == null)
                return false;
            if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
                return false;
            CalendarEvent other = (CalendarEvent) obj;
            if (eventDateTime == null) {
                if (other.eventDateTime != null)
                    return false;
            } else if (!eventDateTime.equals(other.eventDateTime))
                return false;
            return true;
        }
     }
```

Look this part of your code here. For JPA you have declared that entities will be distinguished with `Long id`.

Later however you provide an equals and a hashcode method that considers only `eventDateTime`.

So a list holding CalendarEvents can have multiple CalendarEvents with the same id and different eventDateTime. That is definitely wrong for JPA.

Start by implementing equals and hashcode which consider only Long id field. If that is not the specific root cause we will go further but this must definitely change considering how you use CalendarEvents

```
old_events = user.getEvents(); //DB fetch
old_events.addAll(new_events);
Set<CalendarEvent> set_event = new HashSet<CalendarEvent>(old_events);
```

Here you get affected by your wrong hashcode and equals.
You try to filter in a set the unique events. But the set will keep only the events with unique eventDateTime.
Considering that in your code you add 2 times the same elements in a collection, most of them will have the same id.

Later during persist JPA will not expect that to come.

Comment: I have added complete code for the relevant files. Hope that will help.

Answer (score 0):

A user can attend many events.
An event can have many users.
So it will be @ManyToMany mapping.
use only two tables Calendrevent and User

User:

```
@Entity
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;
    private String name;
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable( name ="user_events", joinColume = @JoinColume(name = "user_id"), inverseJoinColume = @JoinColume(name = "event_id"))
    private List<Event> events = new ArrayList<>();
```

Event:

```
@Entity
public class Event {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;    
    private String title;
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
    private LocalDateTime eventDateTime;
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "events")
    private List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();
```

Save user after adding each event in User entity.